# DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime() Has the Wrong Year

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, globalization, datetime-format

And Idea Why the Year appears as **2555**?

[image]

The culture of the site is Thai

Comment: As a side-note: Use `DateTime.UtcNow` instead of `DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime()`. It's faster and cleaner.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes - any time `DateTime` is converted to a string with no explicit culture specified, it will use the current culture's calendar system. However, the `DateTime` components themselves still reflect the Gregorian calendar.

You'll see the 2555 if you use:

```
int thaiYear = new ThaiBuddhistCalendar().GetYear(DateTime.Now);
```

Basically, if you want to get culture-specific date information programmatically, you need to use a `System.Globalization.Calendar`. When formatting a date, make sure you specify the right culture for the calendar you want to use.

Comment: But why does it have two different values, `2555 & 2012`? Shouldn't they both be 2555 or same?

Comment: @Kaf: No, because as I said in the second sentence of my answer, `DateTime` itself always reports values according to the Gregorian calendar. A `DateTime` value doesn't "know" which calendar it's to be interpreted in, so it always assumes Gregorian.

Comment: @Kaf Conversion to string uses the current calendar, but properties like `Year` do not.

Comment: SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters["StartDateTime"].DefaultValue =DateTime.UtcNow.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Is giving me the correct time that I need (the 2012 as the year)
But then I get a SQL error: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

But If I do: =DateTime.UtcNow.ToString();

I get error:

Comment: @aron: Are you passing values to SQL directly *in* the SQL? If so, that's your problem - use parameterized SQL instead. At the moment you basically haven't given us enough information about what you're doing. I've explained why you're seeing the behaviour you're seeing.

Comment: @aron: Ah, I've just read again. Why are you converting the `DateTime` value to a string at all in the parameter? Just use `SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters["StartDateTime"].DefaultValue =DateTime.UtcNow`

Answer (score 0):

The Thai have a different calendar.

Let me quote:

> There is a 543 years difference between the Buddhist calendar and the
>   Gregorian calendar. Year 2012 in Europe is year 2555 in Thailand.

From http://www.thaiworldview.com/feast/feast.htm